# Remove big app icon under my notification?

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I made a notification by android, which shows my app icon under it, but I can't remove it. How can this be done?

[image: my screen shot]

Here is my code :

```
 public void MakeEventsNotification(int num){

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, BazardanApp.class);
    Bundle parcerable = new Bundle();
    parcerable.putChar("clicknotify", 'E');
    myIntent.putExtra("clicknotify", parcerable);
    PendingIntent myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, myIntent, 0);


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder  = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("بازاردان")
            .setContentText("شما " + num + " رویداد جدید در بازاردان دارید ...")
            .setNumber(num)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.iconminmin)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(that.getResources(), R.drawable.iconmin))
            .setContentIntent(myPendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    builder.setSound(uri);
    long[] v = {500,1000};
    builder.setVibrate(v);

    Notification myNotification;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
         myNotification = builder.addAction(R.drawable.icon, "نمایش رویدادها", myPendingIntent).build();
    }else {
         myNotification = builder.getNotification();
    }
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, myNotification);


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your edit ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used setLargeIcon() just comment that line it thats it

```
public void MakeEventsNotification(int num){

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, BazardanApp.class);
    Bundle parcerable = new Bundle();
    parcerable.putChar("clicknotify", 'E');
    myIntent.putExtra("clicknotify", parcerable);
    PendingIntent myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, myIntent, 0);


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder  = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("بازاردان")
            .setContentText("شما " + num + " رویداد جدید در بازاردان دارید ...")
            .setNumber(num)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.iconminmin)
            //.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(that.getResources(), R.drawable.iconmin))
            .setContentIntent(myPendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    builder.setSound(uri);
    long[] v = {500,1000};
    builder.setVibrate(v);

    Notification myNotification;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
         myNotification = builder.addAction(R.drawable.icon, "نمایش رویدادها", myPendingIntent).build();
    }else {
         myNotification = builder.getNotification();
    }
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, myNotification);
}
```

For More Information about Notifications Consult this ->
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

and also this one->
http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html